# How do you test Angular 2 directive that calls a service?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services, angular2-testing

I used angular-cli to create a simple app to illustrate my problem. You can see all the code here:
https://github.com/wholladay/tracking

The directive calls a service whenever the containing element is clicked on. Therefore, I'd like to mock the service and ensure that it is called when a click event is sent to the directive.

Here is my test code:

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import { inject, addProviders } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TestComponentBuilder } from '@angular/compiler/testing';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TrackingDirective } from './tracking.directive';
import { TrackingService } from './tracking.service';

class MockTrackingService extends TrackingService {
  public eventCount = 0;

  public trackEvent(eventName: string) {
    this.eventCount++;
  }
}

describe('TrackingDirective', () => {
  let builder: TestComponentBuilder;
  let mockTrackingService: MockTrackingService;
  let trackingDirective: TrackingDirective;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockTrackingService = new MockTrackingService();
    trackingDirective = new TrackingDirective(mockTrackingService);
    addProviders([
      {provide: TrackingDirective, use: trackingDirective}
    ]);
  });

  beforeEach(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
    builder = tcb;
  }));

  // General button tests
  it('should apply class based on color attribute', (done: () => void) => {
    return builder.createAsync(TestApp).then(fixture => {
      let testComponent = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
      let buttonDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));

      buttonDebugElement.nativeElement.click();
      expect(buttonDebugElement).toBeTruthy();
      expect(mockTrackingService.eventCount).toBe(1);

      done();
    });
  });
});

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `<button tracking="some button"></button>`,
  directives: [TrackingDirective]
})
class TestApp {
}
```

And here is my directive code:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TrackingService } from './tracking.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[tracking]',
  providers: [
    TrackingService
  ]
})
export class TrackingDirective {

  @Input() tracking: string;

  constructor(private trackingService: TrackingService) {
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(element) {
    this.trackingService.trackEvent(this.tracking);
  }
}
```

When I run the tests via `ng test`, the test fails because eventCount is still 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

great question!

You are trying to test a directive that has it's own provider:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[tracking]',
  providers: [
    TrackingService
  ]
})
```

In this case we need to make sure, that our `MockService` is injected in the directive and in our test code. Injecting in the test code is required because you want to check the `eventCount` property. I would suggest creating an Instance of the `MockService` and use this instance as a value for the `TrackungService`:

```js
let mockService = new MockTrackingService();

beforeEach(() => {  
  addProviders([provide(TrackingService, {useValue: mockService})]);
});
```

The **same** instance of the `MockService` needs to be used as provider for our directive:

```js
builder
      .overrideProviders(TrackingDirective, [provide(TrackingService, {useValue: mockService})])
      .createAsync(TestApp).then(fixture => {

...

      done();
    });
```

See the method `overrideProviders` of the `builder`.

So the complete code for your test looks like this:

```js
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import { inject, addProviders } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TestComponentBuilder } from '@angular/compiler/testing';
import { Component, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TrackingDirective } from './tracking.directive';
import { TrackingService } from './tracking.service';

// do not extend the TrackingService. If there are other 
// dependencies this would be difficult or impossible.
class MockTrackingService {
  public eventCount = 0;

  public trackEvent(eventName: string) {
    this.eventCount++;
  }
}

let mockService = new MockTrackingService();

beforeEach(() => {  
  addProviders([provide(TrackingService, {useValue: mockService})]);
});


describe('TrackingDirective', () => {
  let builder: TestComponentBuilder;
  let mockTrackingService: MockTrackingService;

  beforeEach(inject([TestComponentBuilder, TrackingService], 
    (tcb: TestComponentBuilder, _trackingService: TrackingService) => {

    builder = tcb;
    // we need to cast to MockTrackingService because 
    // TrackingService has no eventCount property and we need it
    mockTrackingService = <MockTrackingService> _trackingService;

  }));

  // General button tests
  it('should apply class based on color attribute', (done: () => void) => {

    builder
      .overrideProviders(TrackingDirective, [provide(TrackingService, {useValue: mockService})])
      .createAsync(TestApp).then(fixture => {

      let testComponent = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
      let buttonDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));

      buttonDebugElement.nativeElement.click();

      expect(mockTrackingService.eventCount).toBe(1);

      done();
    });
  });
});

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `<button tracking="some button"></button>`,
  directives: [TrackingDirective]
})
class TestApp {
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much! I knew I was close, but I couldn't figure that last part that I was missing.